# what is the meaning of "heating the tar" here? is it a proverb?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

what is the meaning of "heating the tar" here? is it a proverb?

> Those humble folk who watched over the new birth—Capron, of Auburn,
>   who first lectured upon it in public; Jervis, the gallant Methodist
>   minister, who cried, "I know it is true, and I will face the frowning
>   world!"; George Willetts, the Quaker; Isaac Post, who called the first
>   spiritual meeting; the gallant band who testified upon the Rochester
>   platform while the rowdies were **heating the tar**—all of them are
>   destined to live in history.

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pouring boiling tar off the ramparts of castles or city walls was an early thermal weapon used in medieval times. Also, "[tarring and feathering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarring_and_feathering)" was a form of public torture and humiliation. Both involved heating tar to use in an offensive way.

In your text, "heating the tar" seems to be used as a metaphor to describe people *preparing* for trouble. Calling them "rowdies", or rowdy people, suggests some kind of unrest.

Comment: Or they could have been preparing to [tar and feather](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarring_and_feathering) someone.

Comment: @KateBunting very good point, I suspect that is more likely given the context, added in.